# c# mvc - issue redirecting to action when using custom ActionName attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have an action method that goes like so:

```
// GET: admin/cms/add-page
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("add-page")]
public ActionResult AddPage()
{
    return View("AddPage");
}

// POST: admin/cms/add-page
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("add-page")]
public ActionResult AddPage(PagesVM pagesVM)
{
    ...
    return RedirectToAction("AddPage");
}
```

But the redirect redirects to standard url and not the actual and different `ActionName` - it should redirect to `mysite/admin/cms/AddPage` instead of `mysite/admin/cms/add-page`

Comment: Are you saying that you have another `public ActionResult AddPage` method with an ActionName attribute `AddPage` doesn't make sense, if this is the case you need to rethink your method names.

Comment: First, try changing `return RedirectToAction("AddPage")` to `return View("AddPage")`. It's no use to redirect to other `AddPage` method with different HTTP method.

Comment: Yes I have 2 action methods with same name, one is GET and another POST. In my Q the code is for the POST, which then redirects to GET. and I want to redirect because I do not of a better way to clear up fields in the form after a successful submission.

Comment: Can I simply somehow  redirect to domainroot.com/whatever where I can change whatever to anything else?

Comment: Is that the GET method of a POST method (its not marked with `[HttpPost]`) And if its the POST, then show the GET method.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I've posted both methods now, but cut off the body of the POST because it's just some db stuff. Just to make it clear, everything works fine, I just dont know how to redirect back to GET.

Comment: Still not clear what the issue is. You have decorated the GET method with `[ActionName("add-page")]` which means your redirect needs to be `return RedirectToAction("add-page");` to match the attribute. But the url will be `mysite/admin/cms/add-page` not `mysite/admin/cms/AddPage`. If you want `...cms/AddPage` then remove the attribute

Comment: return RedirectToAction("add-page"); is what I was looking for, works perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to return to the same view and keep the form values use:
    return View(pagesVM);

if you want to return the same view with empty values use:
    return View(new PagesVM()):